# Mapping a polymorphic relationship onto 2 models simultaneously

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comments, polymorphism

I need to relate a Comments model with two ids at the same time but can't figure out how.  Here' my situation.  I am building an [on-line school grading system](http://github.com/rnhurt/gradesheet) and need to be able let the teacher make a comment on a particular student in a particular course for a particular term (grading period).

```
class Course
  has_many :course_terms
  has_many :enrollments
end

class CourseTerm
  belongs_to :course
end

class Student
  has_many :enrollments
  has_many :courses, :through => :enrollments
end

class Enrollment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :course
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :commentable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

I know it looks awfully complex but its pretty simple really.  A course has many terms which a student can be enrolled in.  I want to have comments for a CourseTerm + Student but I don't know if Polymorphic can handle multiple IDs in one comment.  Can I do something like this:

```
class CourseTerm
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable, :source => [:student, :course_term]
end
```

Or do I have to forgo Polymorphics and go with a standard Comment table build with a CourseTerm.id and Student.id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you won't be able to create the mapping you want using polymorphic relationships.  The idea behind polymorphic relationships is to allow a model to belong to one of several other models using *a single* foreign key, with the addition of an extra column that indicates the model that each row refers to.  For comments, the table would look something like:

```
CREATE TABLE comments (
    id                integer primary key,
    commentable_id    integer,
    commentable_type  varchar(255),
    text              text
);
```

But since you want to associate your comments with both users and course terms, a single foreign key is not enough, so you have to use a standard model that belongs to both users and course terms:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :course_term
end
```

Comment: Darn you and your logic.  :)   I was hoping that Rails might have some more *magic* in its pouch to make this all just work.  Oh well, it looks like I have to do it the hard way.

Thanx for the help!